# Is it ever practical to store primary keys of one table as text in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine if we had millions of rows in Table A.

For each large row (10+ columns) of Table A, we might have 20+ rows that are exact duplicates except for a singular column where we store an ID for Table B.

Would it be more EFFICIENT and/or MEMORY SAVING to store in Table A, the ID's for Table B in a text field ---> "B_ID1|B_ID2|B_ID3" etc and then return this data client-side, parse it, and then send it out for the actual data from Table B.

This is assuming we had 2+ million rows of unique data in Table A and if we stored that additional column outside the text field, we would add 2 Million*20+ Rows to that individual table with all that extra wasted space.

Or am I very naive in my approach and understanding of SQL? I literally just started using it like a week ago and taught myself the basics for my app.

Comment: Part of my reasoning....Is that if a hacker manages to get the data in Table B - all of it - they cannot find out at all how it links back to Table A easily. If they get the data in Table A - its going to take them a longer time to figure out how to get the data in Table B.

Comment: As a general rule, if you find yourself concatenating IDs into text fields something has gone horribly wrong. Instead I think you want three tables. Table-A that is de-duplicated because it does NOT contain any Table-B IDs, Table B, and a new third "A-to-B" mapping table,  which contains the linkages of A1->B1, A1->B2, A1->B3, A2->B4, etc.

Comment: If you're concerned with securing the data, I'd say just encrypt it before storing. The key then resides elsewhere, unbeknownst to the hacker.

Comment: I hope to include encryption later if I can, but only if its really necessary. I'm sort of new to SQL, PHP, and a lot of this. I just started coding like 1-2 years ago and am trying to develop my first start-up - the reason I went back to school to learn to code. Although I'm finding myself a bit overwhelmed at the amount of work ahead of me.

Answer (score 1):

This is where a [weak entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_entity) (table) is best used.

Instead of duplicating all the data in table A, you simply create a new table that links A to B. In it, you can have only the ID to table A that links to the several ID's in table B (and set the primary key to be both of the foreign keys).

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself duplicating a lot of data across multiple rows, it may indicate that your database isn't normalized (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

This means that you might be able to break it into multiple smaller tables that reference each other to avoid data duplication.

Answer (score 0):

SQL provides the ability to index your table in a variety of ways. I'm not an expert on big data, but my first hunch would be no. Having an auto-incrementing, indexed primary key lets the SQL server do the work of maintaining the list of records in a way it can easily look up info you need.

The real question comes down to how you are needing to parse/interact with this 2 million some odd rows. Is it a bunch of split document info? User profiles? Is it real-time inputs from some hardware device? Context is key to determining if SQL is even the best way to approach the problem.

Can you give us a little context on what sort of project you're theorizing? Or is this a more hypothetical question?

UPDATE: Check out [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/) for a brief intro to SQL concepts (among other coding references)

Comment: Thank you. Without giving it away entirely - imagine each entity in Table A was every item in a grocery store and Table B was all the reviews on that individual item. I'm sure it probably doesn't make sense anymore what I was trying. I was just liking the idea of all the reviews not having a trace back to where they came from for security reasons.

Comment: So create a table for reviews that doesn't contain any user information. It would have a FK out to the PK on the Grocery table to link a review to a particular item. You maintain anonymity if you simply don't store any Personally Identifiable Information.